# WCF service certificate and client side endpoint identity - why it doesn't work?

Tags: wcf, security, certificate

[Update] - I attach also full config files, for [service](http://gist.github.com/230024), and for [client](http://gist.github.com/230026) (outside of here, not to flood the topic)

I'm having situation pretty much identical to the one outlined in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1577115/wcf-service-certificate-implications-of-certificatevalidationmodenone-and-revo) question, however my question is somewhat different.

- I'm using NetTcpBinding with security
  set to TransportWithMessageCredential
- I'm using Password/Username
  credentials backed up by ASP.NET
  provider
- My service is self hosted in Windows
  Service
- I **do** have in my endpoint behavior
  specified authentication
  revocationMode="NoCheck"

It is required that the service provides a certificate to authenticate itself to clients. That's OK, I just do:

```
<serviceCertificate findValue="***"
                    storeLocation="CurrentUser"
                    storeName="My"
                    x509FindType="FindByThumbprint"/>
```

Now, I somewhat imagined that now the client would end up having

```
<identity>
  <certificate encodedValue="encoded certificate"/>
</identity>
```

And it will be able to verify service's credentials **without having that certificate installed in the store on client machine**.

I was surprised [to learn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733130.aspx) that although I set the service credentials to certificate, [WSDL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Services_Description_Language) exposes

```
<Identity>
   <Dns>Foo</Dns>
</Identity>
```

Again, on service I can set Identity to CertificateReference and hook it up to the same certificate, and then WSDL will expose identity as X509Certificate, but when I run the client that setting is ignored, and I end up with error message:

> System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityNegotiationException:
>   The X.509 certificate CN=xxx is not in
>   the trusted people store. The X.509
>   certificate CN=xxx chain building
>   failed. The certificate that was used
>   has a trust chain that can not be
>   verified. Replace the certificate or
>   change the certificateValidationMode.
>   A certificate chain processed, but
>   terminated in a root certificate which
>   is not trusted by the trust provider.

Is there a way to make client use that value from config and work without having to install a service certificate (nor its root) on client' machine?

**[UPDATE]**
While setting certificateValidationMode to none will make the exception go away, it is unacceptable solution from security point of view.

It makes the client merely acknowledge that it receive ''some'' certificate, without getting into details. This makes all range of man in the middle attacks possible. It still won't validate the information sent by (alleged) service against the certificate dumped in the config.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution sketch:

1) Define and register a custom **X509CertificateValidator** on the client

2) In the **Validate** method, compare the given certificate with the one present in the client's **EndpointAddress.Identity** property. The object referenced by this property should have the **X509CertificateEndpointIdentity** exact type.

I didn't test this solution, however it makes perfect sense to me.

HTH
Pedro

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. I have a question though - why does it not work out of the box? If the client has all the required information, and receives some certificate from a service, it is the most natural thing to do to validate one against the other. Why doesn't WCF do this?

Comment: Conjecture: for security reasons. Using the proposed solution, the WSDL import process security becomes even more critical, since no additional certificate verification will be performed when communicating with the service.

Comment: I've just started a bounty on my own question that seems similar to what you're saying here.  If you can spell out the solution in more detail there, I'd much appreciate it! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4579666/wcf-newbie-how-to-install-and-use-a-ssl-certificate

Answer (score 2):

> [UPDATE] While setting
>   certificateValidationMode to none will
>   make the exception go away, it is
>   unacceptable solution from security
>   point of view.
>
> It makes the client merely acknowledge
>   that it receive ''some'' certificate,
>   without getting into details. This
>   makes all range of man in the middle
>   attacks possible. It still won't
>   validate the information sent by
>   (alleged) service against the
>   certificate dumped in the config.

You are wrong. This will do perfectly. That's actually what you want - your certificate to **not** be validated.
All you need is to set the identity of the endpoint on the client to

```
<identity>
  <certificate encodedValue="encoded certificate"/>
</identity>
```

When the client connects to the server WCF will compare the two certificates and throw an exception if they do not match. And you are perfectly safe.

Using a custom validator like **Pedro Felix** suggested is completely unnecessary in your case. That's exactly what the endpoint identity is for.

Comment: This is misleading - setting certificateValidationMode to None means you can have any encodedValue and it will not be checked.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, I cannot comment on other answers.

I just tested this in .NET 4.0 and I can confirm that the "Zeratul"'s answer is correct. Explicitly settings the identity of the service either in config, or programmatically is sufficient for server authentication. There is no need to validate certificate by any other means (i.e. you can set "certificateValidationMode" to "None") since you are using the ultimate validation method - comparison of the thumbprint of the certificate.

@AlexDrenea

"serviceCertificate" is not used for validation. It is used with message security to encrypt messages before they are sent to the server. See Microsoft's documentation about this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731782.aspx

Answer (score 1):

This is an additional comment to my previous answer. Sorry I cannot comment answers.

Moreover you do **not** need to set **any** identity on the server. Forget about what WSDL tells you about the identity of the server. The identity of a remote service endpoint is decided by the client during runtime. If the server uses SSL then it has several identities: the common name of the certificate (i.e. a DNS identity), a certificate identity and an RSA identity (not sure about the last one). Therefore, you can check the server's identity by anyone of these criteria (or by several of them).

Answer (score 0):

You are corect and almost finished configuring the client configuration. You are missing one last thing (as mentioned in the error description) : you need to set the revocationMode to NoCheck in the configuration:

```
 <behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="SecureMessageUserName">
      <clientCredentials>
         <serviceCertificate>
            <authentication revocationMode="NoCheck"/>
         </serviceCertificate>
      </clientCredentials>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
 </behaviors>
```

If you need more details, just let me know and I'll post a full working client configuration.

**Edit** sorry for the delay

You should also add the noCheck in the server configuration :

```
<behavior name="X509SecureBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <serviceCredentials>
            <serviceCertificate storeName="My" storeLocation="CurrentUser" x509FindType="FindByThumbprint" findValue="aaaa" />
            <clientCertificate>
              <authentication certificateValidationMode="None" revocationMode="NoCheck" />
            </clientCertificate>
          </serviceCredentials>
        </behavior>
```

Also I didn't include the certificate reference in the endpoint definition.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I do have this option set. I updated the question accordingly.

Anyway, the certificate seems to be ignored regardless of what I specify here.

Comment: could you post a full configuration file ? or the significant part of it ?

Comment: Sure I can, I linked them, because they are pretty big, and I don't want to scare off potentially helpful people by drowning them in tons of xml

Comment: I'm not grumbling, but this solution does not  cut it for me :(

Comment: I'm not sure I understand wht you mean? It doensn't work or you can't edit the server's config from other reasons?

Comment: Take a look at my updated question (at the bottom). Basically it does make the exception go away, and calls to succeed but it does not make the client use the certificate serialized in config - it just makes it accept ANY certificate, which is unacceptable unfortunately :/